# Are my steps correct for a proper classification of a sick brain?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, data-preprocessing, brain

I have a dataset with **MRI** of patients with a specific disease that affects the **brain** and another dataset with **MRI** of healthy patients.

I want to create a **classifier** (using neural networks) to classify if the MRI of a new patient shows the presence of the illness or not.

First of all, I **extracted** the brain from all the MRIs (the so-called **skull stripping**) using [BET](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/BET) tool found in FSL.

I have three questions for you

1. As the input to the **training** phase, I want to give the **whole** extracted brains (possibly in the nii format). What kind of **preprocessing** steps do I need to apply once I've **extracted** the brains (before passing it to the classifier)?
2. Do you know any better tool for **skull stripping**?
3. Do you know a tool (or library) that takes as input a nii files and allows me to create a classifier that uses neural networks?

Comment: Please, focus on one question only. I would remove at least the second question and maybe leave the 3rd question as a side note.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like everything you want is available with the [Deep Learning Toolkit (DLTK) for Medical Imaging](https://dltk.github.io/)

There is also a blog: [An Introduction to Biomedical Image Analysis with TensorFlow and DLTK](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2018/07/an-introduction-to-biomedical-image-analysis-tensorflow-dltk.html)

There is a DataCamp course that walks you through most of the process but instead of a classifier they use deep learning to reconstruct brain images.  They provide a link to their MNIST classifier example which should be easy to adapt for your purpose.  See: [Reconstructing Brain MRI Images Using Deep Learning (Convolutional Autoencoder)](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/reconstructing-brain-images-deep-learning)

ResearchGate has a thread that may help:
[What is the appropriate way to use Nifti files in deep learning?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_appropriate_way_to_use_Nifti_files_in_deep_learning)